# Converting parametric equations in a numerical equation

Tags: parametric

Is it possible convert this parametric equations in a numerical equation?

$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle x(t)=tv_0\cos(\theta)\\
\displaystyle y(t)=tv_0\sin(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+h
\end{cases}
$$

Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation#Conversion_from_two_parametric_equations_to_a_single_equation) Wikipedia's entry, at:

*"Conversion from two parametric equations to a single equation"*

Comment: "Numerical equation"? Can you given an example of what you mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio look at my answer, is it correct, right?

Comment: Unclear question followed by an unclear solution. What can one say about it?

Comment: Answer...to what, @FormlessCloud?! You just wrote in your "answer" a mathematical expression which I've no idea what it is and what its relation with your question is.

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry, look at my updated question...

Comment: @FormlessCloud, I'm sorry to say this but your answer below *still* makes no sense. I know what is to try to make parametric equations into one single **equation**, but below you did NOT write any equation but only an expression!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

$$
y=h+\left(x\tan(\theta)-\frac{g}{2v_0\cos^2(\theta)}x^2\right)
$$